# Getting Hour value from time string in Swift

Tags: swift, nsdateformatter

I am trying to get an Int value for Hour from a string.

```
let time = 13:24
    func getNtfHour() -> Date{
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH"
        let result = dateFormatter.date(from: time)!
        return result //2000-01-01 08:24:00 +0000
    }
```

As you can see my current code return a whole date and the time does not match with the string. How do I fix it?

edit: I managed to to this by using date components

```
    let time = 13:24
    func getNtfHour() -> Int{
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
        let result = dateFormatter.date(from: time)!
        let calendar = Calendar.current.component(.hour, from: result)
        return calendar //13
    }
```

Comment: Hint: dateComponents

Comment: Your code should crash. How do you think that the iOS know how to match `HH` with `13:24`?

Answer (score 0):

As a time string is actually not related to a *Date*formatter an easier way is to parse the string directly.

If the hour has always two digits

```
let time = "13:24"
let hour = Int(time.prefix(2))
```

or otherwise

```
let time = "13:24"
if let range = time.range(of: "^\\d+", options: .regularExpression) {
    let hour = Int(time[range])
}
```